# how to store byte array in neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

I am unable to create a node in neo4j database to store byte array through java code. Please can anybody help?

String q = "create(userImage:UserImage{imageBytess:'"+imageBytes+"'})";
This stores as String. I am not getting how to do for bytes

Comment: Storing BLOBs as property values is a [really bad practice](https://neo4j.com/blog/dark-side-neo4j-worst-practices/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this :

```
// Given
byte[] byteArray = "hello, world".getBytes();

// When
StatementResult result = session.run("CREATE (a {value:{value}}) RETURN a.value", parameters( "value", byteArray ) );
```

Comment: Thank you, But its says create method parameters. run() seems to accept (string, value) parameters and not (string , any other) parameter like map

Comment: This example comes directly from the tests of the neo4j java driver : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver/blob/16ef4fa05a3f348cd141e966d0d68faafd1dc6e7/driver/src/test/java/org/neo4j/driver/v1/integration/ParametersIT.java#L169-L188 What version are you using ?